# adf.test returning p > 0.99 with xts, but returning p < 0.01 with coredata(xts)

Tags: r, xts

Here is the output:

```
library(tseries) # for adf.test function

adf.test(data)
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  data
Dickey-Fuller = 11.1451, Lag order = 16, p-value = 0.99
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(spread.princomp) : p-value greater than printed p-value

adf.test(coredata(data))
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  coredata(data)
Dickey-Fuller = -4.031, Lag order = 16, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(coredata(spread.princomp)) :
p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

The underlying data is a numeric vector.  People seem to be successful at applying adf.test with xts, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Please let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: You should include the name of the package for `adf.test`.

Comment: This may be related to a [recent thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/11441/focus=11470) over in the land of snark.

Comment: The best way to test for unit root is to use  the `urca` package it's usually safer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?adf.test` says that `x` (the first argument) should be a numeric vector or time series.  By "time series", it means a `ts` classed object, not *any* time-series class object.  You should convert your xts object to a `ts` object before calling `adf.test`.

For example:

```
library(tseries)
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix[,1])
adf.test(as.ts(x))
```

Comment: @tmakino: yes, that's because `diff.zoo` and `diff.ts` do not pad with leading `NA`, while `diff.xts` does.